# Sometimes findOneandUpdate inserts double

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a problem that MongoDB inserts the same documents twice. However, it is so rare a situation.

I am coding a live stats website which is including only soccer stats. To insert a document to the database first I check if there is the same match or not. Then, if there is a match update it with a new value. That's it. I can not share all codes but I am using the findOneandUpdate method with upsert option. In the findOneandUpdate method, I have to modify the returned document from the callback then after I save it with "doc.save()". In that script, I am using Cronjob (node-cron library) and it is running every minute. Most of the time I am getting the results that I want updated with new results if there exists. But sometimes results are inserted twice as you can see in the image.

[image: mongodb]

```
//in async forEach,
 await MatchObject.findOneAndUpdate({matchid: id}, // find a document with that filter
    modelDoc, // document to insert when nothing was found
    {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true, useFindAndModify: false}, // options
    function (err, doc) { }) 
//Also inside findOneAndUpdate method i have save method that is modified with returned document from findOneAndUpdate method.
doc.save().then(res => console.log(res));
```

node v11.15.0
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
mongoDB version v4.0.10
mongoose 5.6.2

Comment: Why you need to call `doc.save()` inside `findOneAndUpdate`???

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc because I need to modify returned document from the findOneAndUpdate callback. Then I save it again.